# Count number of records with matching values in separate fields

Tags: sql, count

I have a table (myTable) as such:

```
id  | name  | orig_id
----+-------+--------
01  | Bill  | -
02  | Tom   | 01
03  | Sam   | 01
04  | Alex  | 02
05  | Phil  | -
06  | Bob   | 01
```

I'd like a query that returns each record but with an added column containing the count of other rows that have an orig_id equal to the current row's id.
The resulting table would look like this:

```
id  | name  | orig_id | mycount
----+-------+---------+--------
01  | Bill  | -       | 3
02  | Tom   | 01      | 1
03  | Sam   | 01      | 0
04  | Alex  | 02      | 0
05  | Phil  | -       | 0
06  | Bob   | 01      | 0
```

I've tried the following query, but get no results:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(t.name) AS mycount
FROM "myTable" AS t
WHERE t.id=t.orig_id
GROUP BY t.id;
```

How can I achieve the desired results?

Comment: Why does Sam have count 0 when Tom has 1, but both have origid 01? Shouldn't Sam also have count 1

Comment: Sam has a 0 count because no other record has an orig_id that is equal to his id (03).  Tom has a count of 1 because Alex's orig_id is equal to Tom's id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a join and aggregation:

```
SELECT t.*, tsum.mycount 
FROM myTable t join
     (select orig_id, count(name) as mycount
      from myTable
      group by orig_id
     ) tsum
     on t.id = tsum.orig_id;
```

Comment: how do I update this query to show the records with mycount=0?

Answer (score 0):

A simple `left join` with count will do it:

```
select t.id, t.name, t.orig_id, count(o.id) mycount 
from myTable t
left join myTable o on t.id = o.orig_id
group by t.id, t.name, t.orig_id
```

See a [live demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6528/2) that produces this result:

```
ID  NAME    ORIG_ID MYCOUNTÂ 
01  Bill    (null)  3
02  Tom     01      1
03  Sam     01      0
04  Alex    02      0
05  Phil    (null)  0
06  Bob     01      0
```