# How to get the count of a grouped by rows - SQL

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

So I have this table

table: "tbl_hash"

```
 ------------------------------
| id | hash1 | hash2 | hash3 |
------------------------------
| 1  |   a   |   b   |   c   |
| 2  |   a   |   b   |   c   |
| 3  |   a   |   g   |   d   |
| 4  |   a   |   g   |   d   |
| 5  |   a   |   g   |   d   |
------------------------------
```

I only want to group them by hash1, hash2, and hash3. count them and only return the count which is higher by 2.

So I have this query to get the values I wanted:

```
select CONCAT(hash1, hash2, hash3) as hashes, COUNT(*) as count from `tbl_hash` group by hashes having `count` > 2 limit 5
```

^^ the query above works perfectly..

But what If I wanted to get the data and count for each row? Expected output:

```
--------------------------------------
| id | hash1 | hash2 | hash3 | count | 
--------------------------------------
| 1  |   a   |   b   |   c   |   2   |
| 2  |   a   |   b   |   c   |   2   |
| 3  |   a   |   g   |   d   |   3   |
| 4  |   a   |   g   |   d   |   3   |
| 5  |   a   |   g   |   d   |   3   |
--------------------------------------
```

I'm also planning on converting those to a query builder using `DB::table...`

Comment: What if there's a fourth hash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count number of records with matching values in separate fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310126/count-number-of-records-with-matching-values-in-separate-fields)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may join your original table to a subquery which finds the counts for each group:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.cnt
FROM tbl_hash t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT hash1, hash2, hash3, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM tbl_hash
    GROUP BY hash1, hash2, hash3
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
) t2
     ON t1.hash1 = t2.hash1 AND
        t1.hash2 = t2.hash2 AND
        t1.hash3 = t2.hash3;
```

Note that what I wrote above would completely filter off any original records belonging to a hash1/hash2/hash3 group which did not have a count greater than 2.  If you instead want all records, with the count, then remove the `HAVING` clause.

As a side note, in databases which support analytic functions, such as SQL Server and Oracle, we could write a much less verbose query using `COUNT` as an analytic function.  At some point, mainstream versions of MySQL will also support this.  But for now, we are stuck with doing a join.